# Convert Base64 string to image and save it

Tags: c#, image, base64

I want to save base64 image to a folder in application, but I have a problem in code. it gives an error as below,

> Message = "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."

In my code;

```
public static string UpdateUser(int refuser, string name, string surname,string base64)
        {
            string result = "FAILED";
            var photo = "";

            if (base64!=null && base64!="")
            {


                string mediaPath = Extend.GetXmlConfigParameter("media", "path")+"User\\";
                string mediaName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                base64 = base64.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
                base64 = base64.Replace("data:image/jpg;base64,", "");
                base64 = base64.Replace("data:image/gif;base64,", "");
                base64 = base64.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");

                string filePath = mediaPath + mediaName + ".png";
                try
                {
                    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

                    Image image;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    {
                        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    }

                    image.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    //File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
                    photo = mediaName + ".png";
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                    return result;
                }
            }
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = Database.GetDataSet(con, Database.CreateSpQuery("mobile_user_update ",
                     new List<object> {
                        refuser,
                        name,
                        surname,
                        photo
                     }));
                if (!Database.IsDataSetValid(ds))
                    return null;
                result = Database.GetString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Result"]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

when i try to convert to byte array with below step in code

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

I take this error. my example base64 string is

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMEAAAEFCAMAAABtknO4AAABhlBMVEX////oTD3m5uZMS01PTU8AAADy8vIgICA4OzYPM0egoI7/zMnoSzza29o2Nzb6+vpGRUdBQEIwMDGFhYbIycmxsbLp6enoRzfi4uLv7+/nQzLnRTT0//+bmYnV1dXxTj6oqJjAwMAXFxfJQTTnPiyzs7P98vGzOi+9uq7/0s/mIwvW8/T73tw6OjovLS/ZRzndzMl4d3hZWFrmNCIvMy31sKqWlZb/UDsREREAL0dkZGQAITvX5+b84+HbRznNzcOko6TpXVDraF0AFjTle3H0r6k2Pkrwj4b2u7Z/f3/RursAACSsPTPunZftdmspNjbgpJ4jJyHwlIzEYlnRf3lvbG4AITCmt7fhnJbrYVXoGgDszszeeGuSkourqKAVGxGGhntGNzjNTkMMMzajQjqOPzxsQ0ZcNTNpTU06SVSkTEaARUFMRU7etrHV/P1fZHApMkWSgYc0HTFXOURGOkq9lZXFqqlYb3q71NX7rKZQFRYAFS1kdoGBkJkAAB52O0MqVWNlhJCmctyFAAAgAElEQVR4nNVdi3/a2JVGICAZS0jiISHhEYMtSI0BG5hgm4BXEBzwJDAZdtnG4223nc60TdvspN1tp9mZNLv/+d6Hrl4IELIce0/m57FB3Hu+ex73nHMfRCJh0eT8aBpaY3dB1wzDKO/umoub0FShKEbauWs2ghM3kigAQenfNSOBCSOgCuO7ZiQwceMCRMBQ/3/16LFCYSFwd81JUNphGCQEqXbXnGxPXKVSiURqA4SAUuZ3zc/WdDCfXc0uKhFsyhRTuGuGNlH/3Xh+cVAx/35MKRIjKcP+BBsCpd1zWz6oKoWCommzSR+ZbGWAh16ZRSSsRtIIKNb1dWVTS3dFM8wwJSmD8Q7gkpsVjKGfvsNCYK5qkYmmzC7umtUVRBBAhWcG037kmjJeUaZXhi0/jgwlAPGemvREo0wCoZw27l8besRcjYgaVQoMjDAmd82sJ3EzjaFsIAqD6c5QwtPxaGBMCX00N0iz+zm5VcaURDkxGJxLsxG2CeXdDL2g3Vdr3hk6xADGnCjVZIiFMMMI2vcVQaTyTitIDhCUERONsT6dH6F3lXuLAGC4mEnKMgaJ6Bd+ixm9m9T6lftpDZHKznS4LAU3IkUrDGbzi517mfdwlfm5hya5iWGkQoEaDMePa/dKFv2d+Xm74AOABUNpD6f3JtQ4mA+9rGCzTlGz6T3Qp/7kquDpifzIQipIs8ndCuJ6OtCYYOwTENrw4u7SuP5oEEB73ATD2rvBUJtpAbXHTUyhPf/4BlG5GBRCYR+TMrj4yN61NpSkzXxtQZI0O/iI/PfHYSmQRYzUHn80t1QbKiGzj6kw/EhiuKDCVSCLJOWjZNNTLWwFsohRprdu0JV5CFPAGgiF0S0bQ2WobWbjRqQMb3V6q4xux4btVBje4uxmrArcMim3WNSY3rYKGRBuzRYm7Y8CgKK0W1q8OqBu0ws56Hbqe5XhbU1ky8QMbsMhze1GwCjtqkFaQGBWE21tyUEUZuED2LFiOUlrM8PxqzcXk8nk8XQ00LYHwSiaNJzCBiZvXk5HV5rmmii18PXIdKRSWxu9YXu7JvWvR8qWNq60ry5qCbMFOXo8HbQdjo4ZhO2PakQEWnt83OvtcgmLOK4/rm4x1TFtZSexa2sgsSv3ei+ptl0MhbCDPGOpAyTmx4d52c4/4mB3Mmj79VRKe8ztuhrgEvnDw6liE4N0Fe7UfI3VRKm+6fXyCQMAnDoJll15VvUHQZOuOU62WiAg5HzveGjTRi3cnTF4bVXRjg/ZqMF0JCGrWYDGAMEl5r6MQaJqhgDAB6OqGgVKaDTA9g5tEBgtTAB4fVtqHx+qLBovLpLXY3vxeDzZ0qNkGP3ErUz1YFfGw59t1kED8fQii2XCiWrvcGS1Eao7miBH9PWrQ5Y1pJ9JxU/39pLJvdO4oEcQB7v9rzd71eoISyAS7Z6CFpJ7oIHTLosHIa/2WM10CXAdNyyqICVqj/6DVZERc2ojvpc8jSfjp0kAIt7CmrX7eKM1a0OsMhEdiA9QfG8PtdTBL7Pq4XHbXHUIcWLuw7p0ger1VBYBEHnQfbxbzpZamI8Y9k7y1abouz1BOhTpAL7hBzvZbCcJfo3ruAGVPXxFTIEphKdGO1A52y97LCuiAYR8x1vQkcj0KeKkidRg92KDMWtXWAnzCHgyXoKtl8Afp3E0NgkWkBlAhrhPD26aUyi2h60gUob9x0X0lopY2TtVkXAqGxYRqhfICrgFFl0HN9+FEIQIgqayPVMIhXloqQ40g/YUmHEeDVQLjPtpGr8VjWF1yGAhbHBHwBEhM0piEeRwG3ocywOqEcv2VGIJ0iy0yOKcgZ60x6pQibgsNl88PmoDC6GeRwjWzwkFBfl+YAVJuwyaCMElUaPDmTEMDBUWggqIGzUK6BArYzdiqD4g7jJujCdSow2GoFFYiVqnGHYjC9vIo7/2aJEgMNWoHVZgAV2RNiQIODKCGZVjmwYAQwl21yei2hWeDHiMAKhiWZZz+K89AUkxD9ToDXHKoe1NOoAIRodEBh0y7PHTOAHgE8EAIxAMBEAXT0/jp3Y9BJ30jhWyPyYsd7oDvDxGAAUdyZls7yVNws7Inwy47qn5uT3Sxl5LNhGQjCk0dzohCEAYBi3ZxrjJiGHJb/zIwJSineKXkWUZhLX33ETA5u2G6Oi/g73pq7UIFGmXs3lTZwtZ+Jao3p4MZhCBbUZzElaijd5Ui9pnNAeAGJ7RoAy+INXxUBEoyJvi5CCyxIAxoXG99TMa0z7GCOS4S4x7p3kzqrC8aWjLCdCSGTijsSS47johxBc4Ot5lN5Tmq68OcWha3nMaE3BlwJC5qAoRmMMQojfFnbOGLcswOLU4OI03cZrF9dYbMtTFHkIgA020DUI8Xjaia6hErFm80cJalarBeE0Z9JAQcIIQ6aTjMMUB+Um8nsOJJif2NhbnteOekSCIrVPSwmkLZzgwrgMieGkOgxbmnAym+DcIAckyWf2yVU8LrUxORN3LCdkywdUIRj2cDYEWSp1FLJ3mu50SF0FzAQLAsgMyDOHVjDik3UAIsH2cKEMxcLIYFWUz05fZw8HGRFmqHvdEs9SREKNRMUHqHcgIVMuOKWkYZmxK4SzTBsFFMui7ugkAEILWM2J0F2EVApOBVbSRwltHMDaOVt+gOQEGFy4eYN2kx/pa5gd5BhyDpQZYDKBnk2OIGQ4p2CnHGIKalx3dyzKr9vKbdQiNQxuMA0o07A1E8dCwh2ObNwstqLCqvkqbSEFl86KBQhbzKkjQVc3nEpX09RTkSipLPp8A7KvYhnu9mV0RQ1wfnxLvACH0WAKCzefz+Bf28I3ke41Nao9h1QOS1QASgDp0lGtCXMmZWlWo6owlECzqHU6rBebcH4BzhmlLam+plR6YCJwFeCa8wxfGUQLqnCoW29RLIG2rf/j7m0G1SB352a0J6eic0tpz1d4IaIU9HlWVIuzDRECFt1HE2KPPUPv7VFHTpNEb9hBQD/14M6baJ8z+vt/9dgxzvn9UbCvDl2rPbOT41UBrF5mj/SOrlTBrdjukeFA8f/QIgGhX21ez+auXcP1Iqbalo/1H50V//EMqFvdBK+CDFGrk1fiqUEXsP3IMQ4gTWqRm6ifo5xEAccQoWhuRdg46Bj1vAcAYCdAKaAQ0A34Ujvb30djY5RjmgYW+FbAxTBGw/AIyAAn8/4W7Z38Yjh69IK2gRuAoOFsJs3bddxhpEVgt7BXT/tH2/KNWgDlYjeyfu/kPdUJbWgxnAAHtAXTELPfsk8AHAQjUCIDj0UqYC/uVmTvigRiKgJib7fhFbaxqJMyzeJXRx9uQYEMQ4mImN7/VfUWM5OnJ2mFuM5p6ZY+S0taUG+47ZSToUY/2PSAwVIgAIhceCIovvng8GsJpQQkmIUaB88lgdHGQ/+Fk+W1pGCaCiQePxUd/j3CV/g7cGtKuVgEzBYnZbNkMPAECcFfhlDze6cPDzLt/9kIQ4nQAwgqPzVHF/R/I25Xa5GI6mg0HlKQBpUCkAJIMKsA/wGtoFpeoq+FoPL04sAz177/1QBDubRcHg2UETPG/e/ZnuEql368d7LycjiGYARhrxDREI1GDwXA4m76b7FzXwLA7bVT+Hy87CHd/Ts0DAXXy7Q8ej76HYAyqQFDgR4KrwD8jf2e9Gmef/cVL97TrMBH0rzy6YE5+fL/0pB7/+8pWuIfP9fwS/++fPP3g6YpC3ajmvceu+O1z3fXgz588/WllK/rzs6fP3mdtr3Cln549PTv71gvBINzdOUthBYbw4fnrnEyUmpNzr5+fPXy+LBj89vvnDwE9ff7k9Q//+x7QT68fPvnH07OHZ/954oEgxKVYRN5hRXH/7Mfnz97nStlstqRfPnv+BPL4j/dek2n0JwQA0NmTHw16cob+fuHhicIsdyHy3q7MnHw4Qwy9ffvkx6eYHzjM35fcn2ffP3v60JvO3p54zSGFkE/Fe4YV0KP+15kHU0/+cfZDp5xF9RiWVXM/PXz+3Os5BODsG8+oqPAqXASPV5TVi5QnhIdnPz59CoXy7O1DIJ0fn6xgHz75nWeCwUghb9ecrKpnFYtvV48uodX8Pzz74KlD4d+6c7BycabILEvh7AkiIAKDABrjpTN/AACFvG+5wlRXJTlF6k82voDOPH3yutXM/PVvX3zxxbFB4Ne//fXPl93XZ1i5TCl9KHoXOaRq2GfiRfmCaq8IoosnHwxNOnvy9vvv9S92aiBAqtUOAO1ggr/WDmogbHqjX37/zLCLs7cfvGYCGHYPxiGfwE7kxV1xKq3YRsecHH2AYnjyunN8AFnfWUkH8P3rvy3ARAZmsn0vFWK09vBxZXc3GioEOQqXiyqzqrc5gIT9D0AAi2jtYA33FoqDyp+BKn1X9PBCTPtrZlLhRNBhIkQAHBuFJO7WZu22tz2cnHz3l+vaZvYNSrT+yCwLAKiPND6IcNE87M4zkA1IYtSgBLcz0zx0iSkCayjM1yqQjWr9i2+WLUACKee0BlXW6E0ODQBHAICxSXD9kbYkh/0jpsgUAQMH/drBWk2ChnBwsXy0GSbN8xrwP4lo3uwuND0yRYAwgGxhSrUdczRDHaHyndLWZvMJ5PLApB3rV+SeJu9GVNt1NB59EB3Y58S8rbOwhJCwN4pHpj9Xqo5DLbiAeE4p8DzI1Wj+7vFkx+Ca+NXJ43fz0XBQAEknrLwemUsdwHilaQ25fy7q7CskdyQ7AUTzcKdpZTJst237QGD9FC4AHIE4Q8LpMVC1gUHovhBYWwHJf7F4frR/dI6lIAHlYcYHmFOnAFBXoQAwHJFbDCDSuBg6PRMYWlSPBjAAf8WigosWuHCBXCdSNygrxD/w/MrQqlkklgCEZAniMgDgWPG9Ywezr792aRMsqr948QjYxfk5uXIG/YTFbrjYcM4g/hmtWh2M+1bs4ME/6edmlPACAJ0SfrsymQEvaJcEg9cXXjxyEYR1xKA4COnO7MKeCLuNjVAIxuy2AhODmR/XHs8AR/ZtLcbSgJ3/faRaQJMK0Byo6Y4j9Fy2ALObGwth1djYxAAEUZnMYQXVdv0JXF8AioPpHC7jFmG1sdqWZtPHfVfcKUdX9nJzY/a0giUxQOofTGcDWHNUTJ0qElKgJ1KY4XxysBw0rxYAohsaM7e28byr+Ur/ejK/ojR4UtGgE3h0sQ0vXppc1zxDfm9Ds0i8GYJ1IlgWAwbNVQ52Lqbj8Wg0Gs//+V92wLhzK7V5gwBuLIRN4wPFsM7U1Ez8X3+uru1gI4Bo9AYAuM2tQzGs5L8Lz3vFk81V1uhDADeEsFkEGIOXGDi1Gzfp0lNSsj/+bxIe+e3BSwx63E7JpSpehFs10/hq3h/5UiLch3uYuIToQEAn3PHB6onGo/mAQuA2OSLnONl6AfaZ59ikDYEs5/NR2yO+LNiigELwaQWERKsKD7nLJ2x6pBvzCnGMvi2AUDAhWL3kPQLsZTLUFY42osiCAGhZgwHl4M5jVjZoPRZICDYR+AIAUx/O4h/0mtgzEJRsmXY+4VsACZsaB5nWHLz5hBC1O/h8oowBLCKrP7KORHtr2wOwf9rnxLNE2KWmE9u4BDvZneHWQrA7ovzWhkd6VbEnDQhAjojiboJ8elsE4HNiVJZFCCTvZEFE//lCgN2RHFAGIkAwH10f7qK/tnZHnNi7BhTtidGEY2pTL6NsRu3onc2C4TIIQdb/1OhEwEWmX7erg+uEHMgbcf+mFRTlfCqKnF0GYvZSVReqHi2VNg2tmMChUSc4gpdtWNEY7/aCpPwVTWIYSarODxMOBKVMtoxksJmDvIAQdAP6ImC917BIy7SHgXIEY/EPfNopg1JJ13Oqnt+sRaKKA4vUxkRpJYI+vv872JY7YxG8+mrXwYCos50SQJHfrEWJEp4P9qK+w1AHgUl+d47GMdDict84+HFe4XxH2S6KZMicHNCfAuudoPKHFOR2sgkubKJvU3EiEFf8vkQcyXH0gKYMEFRQxY8pBNiqY6zio31KzrgomxdhqCSyalTNqusQ1EmKFhxBBO+qCXAcxNiPg3fQ2xGIwJBVUdfFUq6k6usRkAyhGzCugAiwQ5GutkZQw/c2MOgOHnurgPNcVu6U1XJOVnPiGtZkM01rBZyVIQJj3/32R/aNbQhol49DB4AMOtlsuVSK5jpsR8+u5o0rEQSpfHAEFc3S5q3I2OWL3ZgTQUnu5HK6DqKeUnmdDLiOmaNlg7lThACr8/Z7N439+vguKicCMPDlvAjYB/Nabo0MIk0TQTmYKUMExk2M0nDLsKKPl74ZBRqyq3uSheWja1MfkeNNBM1gcQUqmeKvpdn6WJGxTZlRIssIfJKcb5gIhGBNoHDuGq8BbXuRztj4OpLBDRBk90wE8a0qNxZBBMZO0S1PhJDdmfj7zYIhSORs9SI1UFyBKl3G8Y0tdw6SSyiVx8ER2FxRPJ4L1Aau1RnfxbHd/lOyW1+r3UAGtspvwLgCIzBOJG51aJ/cJctQ/eAIxLoNQSuQIWAEOxjBVoZQMTaKG6fyAiEQ86c2BKlAKQKLEPSN8GCbExXGZyhpHByBFVNASgaalTGCiLHQ294CATkLawguEAIzvTFMOYgzMqruRnygbbH7kewTJ7NIIAQtB4JA9QoDgcEOdoz+yNwPsXMDGTgAgBQhOAISZfq/v7hGEBgHhIMgkGUnAiG4LyJVky32808khyvyv55mIy7rRBDPBzBlA8GBccD7yrchzA1DNmNyn+sHDgS6C0GgABsj6Bv5ou8v0uXIcQmzShMEwaULQSaAPzBk0B8w25myeRLWLBBsr0VignYhEAIgMOYDK870meWYR7fMSGT7vkWx6ULQDKBFBAG5s8SvKV+TnZjml8oF8COyI7ALBoBokRmmST4RkBnZumg3UJ7O2SflbqDiL1kJnzpC5c00Jl/0NyCvBEpPRFuCIMjBihUGAhLs+zRljpiBFQwGLNya/qihBluJI5ujyATl81tDK2SHvlWiCbqUF8Hx6am6fqvYSiIrT+RoruQvrjggG0itlCIogii8Mi0eLwVdwyEIyNFcyd+N/OZ5cEvrAi8IAykk43rAYpEok7Un4t8ty1xLxJBtx2s5eFtSwHpJLhPAj6IrpqJZsimpckWCZV/ZPjkGazte21xkymoimDYltv2QCDtSS5lmS6DLBIFRvvJVuCN4rZUf7lLg641061LPgrGR5aAL3BsJNI2GXm/SqUadj8V42uDAGFV/BwXNA+3mHJ7vxugYTQvw/r1Fp6yC+Zbzv8XMF4mwyYTIZnOZVrpRrws0DbqMCWWXXvj6UgTzUgGzSCYueNgcHYvFBEFINvhFJ5fFOzVuDkTG30EQVct6phsT6vVkOgXZRx3SZEIgCHxVXC7IuTnr6QxGQCNJpFJpId1oCPQik9GBQER8JWIC7sHwpV7AxyDC17Bly3rnEqg8aBLqDU3XUykBDxfNd0gsSuJ9X6VH8xyvZDrTDg9bxAgAAB78RvN8HRJPtxaZTq6UxdfDkSsGkLnYCN5ZZ70VzavZEuS826IFATYjoDbROPGpVB31FKMFnXBgIvARnZpf/WS7yUznsVjhsKRB+xgPViye54V6CvLQ6i6amU5Hz5XhkXFVzaPL3uAB5byqwkPk5ZyudzKXi24rBuGnBPBZYKzG2MQw13CMUjzWIiFHOCD3xvhZVzbTG5vnyhEZkOZt/0jvgCCUdLqRTgOUcFwhhzxCCAcavAU0JQ10RODh09bnaXuDMaindUMGxJBNxfBzOZl5r4Nt9iibCICI08ZgGf0Ro4sZI4gYQsTHDAQxQrRFMcewOxCQUQKuyNxmS+IERvKBgLgi2wxe5klXlpmR3gkIkyfzLfMJ4liIJpov2IfBgoOFAP/mTQTmAW/mfDj3OMJgJ/PaNFsUVeKNTuHw2BgzBONSKTuHtJ1P/L5d9ejlP+DfaSzoWMvcNT8xD/AxUqE9W1uzIFfX2StkXN3gAdtxLGb6a/uvFg92KdhH2gJvHwKbURgfNSTNN00OnFc1SNS6TMdEyzBT88yGLsRsboK21IJ26cAS15Y+OZTHjZp2NBgD/QCba5mVCc59E9o6c7CudWAUaryDMYDICHbAYy/hZNE9/l7/CGgbilVCQj+RECwdily4zqG64yPZvglvbEPLFKirC4Qh0RTwdMm7lNtbi9aAsauQXZiOB+DEbwNQW7pax4iPOE7MljuXLZpu6ebTzutNGEa7wmLIIBGkTGM0zXadFhEmXe+tFhR5AEQuFoAKs3SouzBmAetNOr2XTIIJCABO8uRGm5lLXopxYzOng4FBBrbc34qhdLy0DGvd02neumGn4nHjSvGbLyHrKUgPwL8UDHaMjwztCIDrmpnzmtqFUaP34DlZXMK4buA9PsnTum1vI7RM95WDxaO6wb1F6To+7mO/LIqhhvbvZU4Al2R1vYK7VaPq8PueojF/ERaWBoHg9erkpFjcd6kG9WuDbxwXgvlfSDUy6CNHdgTuOErt1m0YPLleqRiWaGK2X5ef4+sd5FkSbEnPNLst/tffffuH3721rqdhisWTk5PffWmwbtgj9PVNNNz2WzQ9krpSN8avGefVvtVbiZbe5OlLVgSst9JJZKNA1b/8zW9+8+WX3xjnI0+K1NE33373W96QqkV0rImgO4TlEY7LpUWdcLqe0SAA6pfZciZNbNSm6V8eKUffvHjxh+/++Ns//SkWe/3awbxBLXYJgedOgESpxfMbuFzNPW062OU3+VaZ09Npm4PBBHJb/ve/j70G/9YSzogolxCWEQAqN4XgAvCeAUH/3TIX0ffIyNeJjcZol7qsJppbQsAUPBFEEtmmICwHcD4heLwXq7fKUdDuV2TUeSvj8MU8ohTntmSGUlYFsly006WFNU7fi03i/10ODahPs4T8SKeBPGRsK74tqsPahuVNmeFUYwpryhtcttPleb8Q7IaAfxiP8MIiR65oWUAjqAdjHyKAE4l1eSBD1SaD6toSEyeWu3XBzNCcEbQLgt0MMMH/gyS6mTUjywSY9m8AAKelMzNNRpdbbi5uyHqzZWvEWwoxM8K2PwoE2Mw5zkZAGfCBAWBnNJMoFAqeS743qXJqfRUEEvLbPREhnm/qWdfyajMNw98lzupLr3gTD79wbapJAxDdSfOxovj+BuC0vZmlOdpptWZvlx5HzDJpGP66iBYyyy96I4CRUWU0nNQkpjDn5gPfu2FsCGB1xQXBzNCcCDIeDenAFy0BSF1G9KQ/BAvYSAVEczNFAz7I/11gFgJaL2e6gjETGS+ZP3gBTiImAo/mS0mgRW62ksDSMw1fUuiShirD7a69tyHIgtQvoeY6IKps0bbySqvVWnRybM6E4Ikgm8TFEBvRDVi54y59QegGPU3uQEBIzmdhtRQS+D+LC+nl9QiiAIELQB0/x/mSQivoDSOeCDxpgwwSe24t4nljWBNNt3S8EKy7WeKjIIjsubwpnTTr19HWBqdK8xu7/wgIcFnTonrXei+fXu9UUy06tnwlw8dGAMIKJwK7WqgCH1tNySbbslYc7gwBmNJsUQXtuuaCja2EwKfKkSgtdO4cAQivLQR0auF6O3u6AkIdCktsCR3fc9htIQCTssUjLywdDPeenOl6DMbnclfwbPSjIgCTsmmudNpDq/WGB4JGE0FNNIVmwKuCwkOgfmVOynS96ymlvWUARomPy9SDTsrhIWDrJgI+6X17lJ52ZRkN09w79VbAm4LCQ5CPEQR0Q/dugmvaIdB1a7UtoqeEgGFFeAjEbtqYeYXuKpVOCFbkQTdo24yRsxft7whBYmEg4PnVo5lYGCjpWNoxAZQbQsBJOTwE3GUau9Nk2eNdQnILL0jySd3RSLbB61szjyg8BJEORiDQax27DCskMaHhggkQBJyUQ0Sg47AitaEdtc7T9aVYWk175q4+KEQEOZjr042NQ5lNJhdLvj9fj7njEJ8UIoIyXKyrtzb3Wcos+yqZ57sej/qgEBGUIIJ0wESFo3kf2L0oXAR1Oh00UWkJsWAfDBGBKgAEq6bjjbSo88E+GCKCPA8y5XTQROUyffcI5BhEENAnRjKNu0fA0SDXrze93vJB9wFBpAVy/XpArw7S7HuAoAmmNCGgT4zQ98AXwcBI4APyod+HqAIVf3l++4Q9kc926rG7zw+AKcdAhpDyez0xl5BFuAGjG0s1knX+HtTsAGX5FN3YOJSJvAq3bGcWLR5uxoUrFrzQDFo2DRdBpJSm0/oa3sGYd5pwn3wa7SwW8O7nRUZXg9/KHC6CiApCTDczHNxvXoLrpkBdkg0B7igGzLe6zUxHL6k3vR4+ZATcJV/XbbyrpTJQF7TPL4XUBfCepsGgl7Oqx4Xb9wBBJBvj0x01qpZyOlD0GNRzrC50q9VdgEEvs/A0QBis3xKCSK4ea6Tr6QYgbKMCvbjs6LmsesM71FdR6Agi5ZihLfU6380ARWfFRLhfs+Sk8BFEEnpz0QSss2F+M9FqugUEgG5zzN10Owg+Jm2DgJwCCRqD3Q7ZEGwIB0qWDC5v8q0AoRLHXn7+wKT1C1lc17bNmG+q90GR5PLiKxuA1FdrE8SM7dEHDz7/ii7dOYZs93MHUw8e/PuarzXLt5zPPvj882aY34K2PSX0By7+AVNrKiVZ98Pg8Qfryuy3TVzzKw+W1iBg6eXnH3yufzSG3cRlPAA8iK+LXJpLIoMQwvkGrgCkewFoLBJ59p8Q/cxO6JV8KemFIGC9+cbEZTwGNB375JNPP/3Emz795LNfJVPLH2rdkUPiOssI0vVffLaCfUyf/arRWJJB0PrWjUldYqXe/Ww9AADhF6200wGn63c3Oas2VkD22uh+shEAgPDZp4s6PCOB2U+eBt6XFQbJnRYPZqXPQepdbzU/3cw+AfGLLjrXnhJazdLHSQBWUkIt64h+CcZ2pQm7CDz32We//GWunL3597eFRhy8aSz/AjkAAAAcSURBVCAK3ejPABZIn7oIv4rcKgsvG7itpPH/APV4xrQzYxA1AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

How can I solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that now. It was hard to tell given the *huge* amount of base64 you've provided for very little reason. Please provide a [mcve] which includes a *minimal* example of the base64, and with no other dependencies. Console applications are always a good start for this sort of thing.

Comment: Fundamentally, it looks like you haven't got valid base64, but we don't know where you're getting it from which makes it very hard to fix anything to do with it. (Does it include line breaks? Maybe that's the issue. I can't remember offhand whether `Convert.FromBase64String` handles line breaks.)

Comment: Your code, copied and pasted, works. I even see "MR BASE" image. I guess the question is if `base64` variable really contains the text that you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you getting this base64 string through url. If so, you should encode it , before it send to the client.

```
 HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64string)
```